# Transposing columns to tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is probably very easy but I can not get my head around it. SQL Server 2008.
I have the following:

```
SELECT userId, accesslevel
FROM accesscontrol.dbo.BADGELINK
```

the results I get are

```
user id         accesslevel
72                 1
72                 5
72                 9
89                 1
89                 4
91                 9
91                 11
```

what I would like is

```
user id       acesslevels
72               1,5,9
89               1,4
91               9,11
```

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server can you do something like:

```
Select B.user_id
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ',' + B1.AccessLevel
        From AccessControl.dbo.BadgeLink As B1
        Where B1.user_id = B.user_id
        Group By B1.AccessLevel
        For Xml Path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') As AccessLevels
From AccessControl.dbo.BadgeLink As B
Group By B.user_id
```

Comment: I use this method often, works well. Might want to test with/without inner GROUP BY to see if it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is an absolutely brilliant article on this topic here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ It lives in my bookmarks and I refer to it often. If this does not fully answer your question, please let me know

Comment: Using a recursive CTE is a clever approach. Verbose, but technically ISO compliant.

Comment: @Thomas, to me it seems that OP does not care so much about ISO conformity, but rather wants to find a method to achieve his goals for SQL server 2008.

Comment: We know that know because the tags have been updated. Originally, the question's only tag was `sql`.

Comment: At the time I wrote my answer and you made a comment to my answer about ISO, the tags were already updated =)